# What is the simplest way to link between .hbs files using handlebars?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, express-handlebars, glitch-framework

I am a complete beginner to handlebars and am trying to modify the simple handlebars template taken from the [example on glitch.com](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/handlebars-setup-example?path=README.md:1:0)

I would like to be able to link between `.hbs` files as I would link between `.html` files but when I try however I am given the message `cannot GET` followed by whatever file I give to it.

Here is a grab of my overall structure for ref;

[image]

Here is the `index.hbs` files I am working with

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  {{> head }}
  <body>
    <a href="views/secondpage.hbs">Link to second page</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Which I would like to link to (for example) this `secondpage.hbs` file;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  {{> head }}
  <body>
    <a href="views/index.hbs">Link back to index</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the code in my `server.js` file

```js
// Generic node.js express init:
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));

const hbs = require('hbs');

hbs.registerPartials(__dirname + '/views/partials/');

app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

app.get("/", (request, response) => {

  let dt = new Date();
  let data = {
    projectName: process.env.PROJECT_DOMAIN,
    luckyNumber: Math.floor(Math.random()*1000),
    serverTime: new Date(),
    ip: (request.headers["x-forwarded-for"]||"").split(",")[0]
  };

  data.json = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);

  response.render('index', data);
});

let listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log('Your app is listening on port ' + listener.address().port);
});
```

and the code in my `watch.json`

```
{
  "install": {
    "include": [
      "^package\\.json$",
      "^\\.env$"
    ]
  },
  "restart": {
    "exclude": [
      "^public/",
      "^dist/"
    ],
    "include": [
      "\\.js$",
      "\\.hbs$",
      "\\.json"
    ]
  },
  "throttle": 100
}
```

If any of the details of the other files is necessary to assist let me know and I can provide.

I appreciate I am probably thinking about this in the wrong way, I have looked at handlebars in more detail and experimented with helpers etc. but it seems overly complicated for what I am trying to achieve, I thought you could write basic `html` within an `hbs` file? I am looking for the most straightforward, generic solution to the problem of linking between views in handlebars.

FWIW I want to use handlebars in a pretty simple fashion, basically just looking to have the equivalent of `php includes` using `partials` instead, so if there is a better way to approach the creation of the app with that in mind I would be grateful for advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code looks alright. What is the problem exactly? When you add `{{> head}}` partial to the `index.hbs` doesn't it render properly?

**EDIT:**

Okay, you have mainly 2 problems with your code:

- You [have no route defined](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) on `express` linking to your `/secondpage` endpoint.
- You are trying to link to a file `<a href="views/secondpage.hbs">Link</a>` instead of linking to an URL endpoint `<a href="/secondpage">Link</a>`.

To fix your code you would have to define the endpoint linking to the `handlebars` file, so you need to change your `server.js` file to something like this.

```
const express = require('express');
const hbs = require('hbs');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
hbs.registerPartials(__dirname + '/views/partials/');

// 1st Page Route (URL Endpoint)

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    const data = {
        projectName: process.env.PROJECT_DOMAIN,
        luckyNumber: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000),
        serverTime: new Date(),
        ip: (request.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || '').split(',')[0],
    };
    data.json = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);

    response.render('index', data);
});

// 2nd Page Route (URL Endpoint)

app.get('/secondpage', (request, response) => {
    response.render('secondpage');
});

const listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log('Your app is listening on port ' + listener.address().port);
});
```

And then you need to fix your HTML links to this on `index.hbs`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  {{> head }}
  <body>
    <a href="/secondpage">Link to second page</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this on `secondpage.hbs`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  {{> head }}
  <body>
    <a href="/">Link back to index</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi @Diogo Capela thanks for your reply - perhaps I wasn't clear enough in my question. The partials work fine, the problem is the links - when I click for example the link to `views/secondpage.hbs` I just get an error in the browser `cannot GET views.secondpage.hbs`. Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Hi, thanks that’s really helpful - but is there not a way to do this in a more scalable way? With this approach, for every page I add I will have to add another line to the server. Is there not a way to define the links dynamically? Thanks very much  for your help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using handlebars I used express-handlebars
Terminal: **npm i express-handlebars**

Handlebars is a Middleware and functions as a Twig (Template Engine) so for your server I'd suggest:

```
// Generic node.js express init:
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));

const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
// added this part
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs ({
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    layoutsDir: ('views', __dirname + 'layouts'),
    partialsDir: ('views', __dirname 'partials'),
    extname: '.hbs'
}));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs')

app.get("/", (request, response) => {

  let dt = new Date();
  let data = {
    projectName: process.env.PROJECT_DOMAIN,
    luckyNumber: Math.floor(Math.random()*1000),
    serverTime: new Date(),
    ip: (request.headers["x-forwarded-for"]||"").split(",")[0]
  };

  data.json = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);

  response.render('index', data);
});

let listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log('Your app is listening on port ' + listener.address().port);
});
```

By doing this, you should have a file in your **layouts folder** named *main.hbs* where you will have that dynamic approach you're looking for. Something that stays the same for all pages. I will insert here a suggestion, feel free to adapt for your code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <!-- CUSTOM CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
      </head>
      <body>

        {{> navigation }}

        <main class="container p-5">
          {{{ body }}}
        </main>

      </body>
    </html>
```

Now when you create a `navigation.hbs` in your **partials folder** you will have the same frontend in all pages in the navigation. This is because we defined in the `server.js` our default template to be `main.hbs`. Whilst for your body, the triple hash (`{{{}}}`) inserts the components of the other .hbs files that you define. Don't forget to create a `index.hbs` file inside the **views folder**.

I learned the basics of hbs by following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GVfAPWLkk0M&list=PLxu8eczvq_GH-6EISYOnG8iQ6K_NqjLH6) tutorial (Note it's in Spanish). The tutorial produces [this](https://github.com/FaztTech/nodejs-notes-app) open-source project (which I am including in case it is useful).